# How can I get the yesterday's data and show it to my form today?

Tags: mysql

The idea is that I have this 'Present' form that is a textbox one that the user can input the data.

Now, I want to show yesterday's data(readonly) for comparing the result yesterday vs the result today.

Ex:
Attendance: (yesterday- readonly textbox)

```
Andy Shrob
Paula Guinto
Mylene Miles
```

Attendance (TODAY)

```
Paula Guinto
Mylene Miles
```

How can I get yesterday and show it so I can see who's present yesterday and who's present today? I'm coding PHP and Javascript

I was thinking of this:

```
mysql_query("Select prestoday, presyesterday
FROM attendance
WHERE ???)
```

All ideas are welcome. ;) Whether it be PHP code or Javascript or MYSQL Query

TABLE STRUCTURE:
mysql_select_db("csdcon", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO attendance (prestoday, presyesterday, userdateinp, yesterdate)
                            VALUES
('$_POST[prestoday]','$_POST[presyesterday]','$_POST[userdateinp]','$_POST[yesterdate]')";

Comment: You should show the table structure

Comment: Hi Pekka, Okay will post it now

Answer (score 4):

```
mysql_query("Select prestoday, presyesterday
FROM attendance
WHERE DATE(`datetimefield`) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Comment: Guys, do you know how to code this? I want to have 'alert pop up menu or validator' that the date inputted by the user should not be the systems date. I want that the date yesterday will be inputted by the user, and it the day is more than of todays.. It will give some error or notice? :D

Answer (score 2):

Mysql query

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

will return yesterday date...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Guys, do you know how to code this? I want to have 'alert pop up menu or validator' that the date inputted by the user should not be the systems date. I want that the date yesterday will be inputted by the user, and it the day is more than of todays.. It will give some error or notice? :D

Answer (score 0):

TO get yesterday date

```
 SELECT DATE_SUB(date_time,INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

To get yesterday results randomly

```
SELECT * from test_table where date_time = DATE_SUB(date_time,INTERVAL 1 DAY) order by rand()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get Date From JavaScript as

```
var today= new Date();
var yesterday = new Date();
yesterday .setDate(today.getDate()-1);

alert('today'+today);
alert('yesterday '+yesterday );
```

Comment: I think the user would need some kind of Server side solution.

Comment: @Gunner, ya its better to manipulate date on server side but user write **All ideas are welcome. ;) Whether it be PHP code or Javascript or MYSQL Query**

Comment: Guys, thanks for helping me. ;) My mind is puzzled and its now almost complete coz of you people. ;) Thanks.

Comment: Guys, do you know how to code this? I want to have 'alert pop up menu or validator' that the date inputted by the user should not be the systems date. I want that the date yesterday will be inputted by the user, and it the day is more than of todays.. It will give some error or notice? :D

Answer (score 0):

Use Date related functions in the WHERE condition:

e.g

```
WHERE ??? = DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

For further reference, see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate).

Comment: Guys, do you know how to code this? I want to have 'alert pop up menu or validator' that the date inputted by the user should not be the systems date. I want that the date yesterday will be inputted by the user, and it the day is more than of todays.. It will give some error or notice? :D

Comment: Please post this as a  new question giving reference to this post.